# NGen ASP.NET to save memory - Native Image not used

Tags: asp.net, .net, ngen

We have a web application which we host, where we deploy the same application to 100+ "tenants" on the same machine(s). 
Managed DLL's memory is not shared between processes by default, that means we load the same DLL 100+ times into memory. Goal is to avoid this, and NGen seems to be the way to go for this, as it specifically allows this to happen.

The ASP.NET application is pre-compiled and all DLL's have been NGen'ed, but it seems that they are not used.

Fusion Log Viewer gives us the following output:

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20.06.2017 @ 16:53:11) ***
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
>   completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ca73b74ba4e3ff27  (Fully-specified) 
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/WebHotel/tenant/ItemService/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   E:\WebHotel\tenant\ItemService\bin LOG: Dynamic Base = E:\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\itemservice\081f93f5 LOG: Cache Base = E:\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\itemservice\081f93f5 LOG: AppName = fd860966 Calling
>   assembly : Product.Core.Library, Version=2.5.12456.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: IL assembly loaded from E:\Temporary ASP.NET Files\itemservice\081f93f5\fd860966\assembly\dl3\08cf29cf\00893e3e_afe9d201\SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.dll.
>
> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20.06.2017 @ 16:53:11) ***
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
>   completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ca73b74ba4e3ff27  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///E:/WebHotel/tenant/ItemService/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   E:\WebHotel\tenant\ItemService\bin LOG: Dynamic Base = E:\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\itemservice\081f93f5 LOG: Cache Base = E:\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\itemservice\081f93f5 LOG: AppName = fd860966 Calling
>   assembly : Product.Core.Library, Version=2.5.12456.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: IL assembly loaded from E:\Temporary ASP.NET Files\itemservice\081f93f5\fd860966\assembly\dl3\08cf29cf\00893e3e_afe9d201\SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.dll.

As you can see it does not load the native image from `C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64`...

Using:
    NGen display "SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ca73b74ba4e3ff27"

gives us:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>ngen display
>   "SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORM SupportClasses, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ca73b74ba4e3ff2 7" Microsoft (R) CLR Native Image
>   Generator - Version 4.6.1087.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> NGEN Roots:
>
> \server\e$\Template\2.5.12456.0\ItemService\bin\SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSuppor
>   NGEN Roots that depend on "SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses,
>   Version=5.1.0.0, Cu lture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ca73b74ba4e3ff27":
>
> \server\e$\Template\2.5.12456.0\WS\bin\SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasse
>   s.dll
>
> Native Images:
>
> SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyTok en=ca73b74ba4e3ff27

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe` seems to be a 32-bit executable, and you're using the 64-bit `ngen.exe`. If your app is 32-bit, you'll need to use the 32-bit `ngen.exe`, or the 64-bit `w3wp.exe` if it's the other way around.

If this is not the issue, you may want to check this blog post (if you haven't already):
https://kceiw.me/net-native-image-troubleshooting

Comment: Hi, the system32 version of w3wp is the 64-bit version. 32-bit is in SysWOW64 folder. (Verified as the AppPool has "Enable 32-bit applications: FALSE") I will go through the steps in the Link and report back, thank you